# Can I have two-way binding on a textarea using ng-list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've seen several examples where a user can enter data into a `<textarea>` and have it be converted into an array.  However if I modify the array internally, the changes are not reflected in the textarea.  Is there a way to make the binding two-way?

Example: the button adds items to the array, but they don't show up in the textarea.  Modifying the textarea overwrites any internal changes.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<textarea ng-init="list=['item1', 'item2']" ng-model="list" ng-list></textarea><br>
<button ng-click="list.push('newitem')">add</button>
<pre>{{ list | json }}</pre>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the reference of `list` changed. `ng-model` does not do deep equality checks.

Try something like `list = list.slice(0); list.push('newitem')`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<textarea ng-init="list=['item1', 'item2']" ng-model="list"></textarea><br>
<button ng-click="list = list.push('newitem')">add</button>
<pre>{{ list | json }}</pre>
</html>
```